# How to add an index page to a sub-sections with mkdocs?

Tags: mkdocs

Let the following nav be:

```
nav:
    - Home: 'index.md'
    - Operations:
      - Training: 'operations/Training.md'
      - Instructions: 'operations/Instructions.md'
```

I would like to have a page be associated with the sub-section `Operations`, meaning that clicking on the `Operations` node in the menu opens it and load the page.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Hi! If I understand correctly, you want to click on the Operations (which contains subsections?) so that it opens your index page (which is home)?